# Problems refreshing stdout line using print with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout

I've been trying to print out the progress of a for loop in python2.7 using the following code:

```
for i in range(100):
    if float(i) % 10.0 == 0:
        print i, "\r",
```

The behaviour I'm after is the refreshing of the same line on std out rather than writing to a new line every time.

EDIT 1:

Testing in my console (Xfce Terminal 0.4.8), I actually don't get any output regardless of whether I include the `if` statement or not.

**Why is there no output?**

I originally said the behaviour of the stdout changed depending on the if statement being there or not because I simplified the code that produced the problem to its most simple form (only to produce the above mentioned effect). My apologies.

EDIT 2:

Thanks to [senderle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552693/1358677), this is solved. If you miss out the `sleep()` command, the prints and carriage return happen so quickly you can't see them.

EDIT 3:

One last thing. If you don't catch for the final number in `range(100)`, i.e. 99, the number is cleared off the screen.

EDIT 4:

Note the comma after `print i` in [senderle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552693/1358677)'s answer.

Comment: For me, in both cases numbers are coming on separate lines. You can redirect the output to a file(or copy-paste to a text editor) and then open it to see the output, rather than looking at the command line.

Comment: What OS are you on? New line behavior is OS dependent (and may even depend on the shell and console that you are using). I ran the code on Windows running the Python 2.7.1 interactive console in PowerShell and both worked the same: 1 number per line.

Comment: works fine for me.. on ubuntu, one line, new numbers overwriting previous

Comment: What's up with `float(i) % 10.0`? (as opposed to `i % 10`)

Comment: I'm still rather stuck in the C mind set. I'm new to python. Hence being explicit about all my variables and what type they are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that using `sys.stdout` is a more system-independent way of doing this, for varions reasons having to do with the way `print` works. But you have to `flush` the buffer explicitly, so I put it in a function.

```
def carriage_return():
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

This is kind of a WAG. Let me know if it helps.

I tried this and it works for me. The `time.sleep` is just for dramatization.

```
import sys, time

def carriage_return():
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()

for i in range(100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print i,
        carriage_return()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Finally, I have seen people do this as well. Using terminal control codes like this seems right in some ways, but it also seems more brittle to me. This works for me with the above code as well (on OS X).

```
def carriage_return():
    if sys.platform.lower().startswith('win'):
        print '\r'
    else:
        print chr(27) + '[A'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tested this instead of `print i, "\r",` and it just wrote the numbers one after the other on new lines.

Comment: Yes, it appears to work. I also tried without the `sleep` command. Without the sleep command, the screen refreshes so quickly that you can't see it.

Comment: I'm curious, why would an escape code be preferred over a simple return?

Comment: @MarkRansom, in all honesty, I'm not sure -- I've just seen it from time to time. As I said, it seems more brittle, since who knows what codes a particular terminal will accept. But on the other hand, `\r` runs afoul of various newline conventions. So they come out about even as far as I can tell.

Comment: @senderle I went and wrote out my own version of your code and drove myself nutty when I couldn't reproduce the original behaviour. Turns out that there is a comma after `print i`(!) which I missed. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your code as is, and just including a :colon: at the end of the first line, works just fine with Py2.7 32bit, Windows7 64-bit.

Do you have any out writes to stdout in your `if` or `for` block that could be causing the new-lines to be written out ?